# What does C.C and V.V stand for?

Tags: code-geass

*Disclaimer: I am not asking about speculation on C.C's (or V.V's) real names*

In Code Geass, C.C implies that she abandoned her real name and has since forgotten it

> Lelouch, do you know why Snow is white? it's because it has forgotten it's name

When talking to Lelouch about if she was human she says that if she wanted to be seen as human she would have **a more human name**, as if she hinting that her name C.C was something she chose. V.V also shares the same kind of name but nothing is ever said about it.

in Etrian Odyssey Untold, the AI in charge for firing Gungnir and Ricky's friend is named Mike however is spelled as M.I.K.E which stands for **M**emetic **I**nstallation **K**eeper **E**ngine.

So i am wondering, does C.C and V.V stand for anything?

Comment: Stands for "Producers deliberately left loose ends to spark debate and interest for their product therefore increasing revenue". Such as leaving the smile of the cart driver on the cutting room's floor.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no information as to a meaning to C.C. or V.V other than to hide their real names.**

There is some information about the planning stages of Code Geass having C2 name as Cera or Sera but I never saw any official information to back that up other than random websites.

In regards C2:

Well if you want the reference from the anime alone, I don't think it was ever revealed, there was a scene where she does say her name involuntarily in her sleep at episode 11 around 18 minutes of the first season, but the name it self is never revealed to us and is covered with droplet of water sound instead.

She whispers her name
[image: she whispers her name]

She confirms it was her name
[image: She confirms it was her name]

Further in he also calls her name right after saying "I learned something interesting because of that" in reference of staying/saving her which was not necessary. And again her name is censored.

Further in she also asks him to call her name again which he does however again its muted/censored.

So to this point the name is only known to Lelouch!

---

In regards V2:

On episode 21 of the second season around 5 minutes and 20 seconds Lelouch's mother tell a set of events of the past along with Charles however V2 name is again never revealed.

[image: twins]

Comment: i don't know the episode number but it's during the Battle or Narita where the Guren is first used, the scene your talking about is after Suzaku and the Lancelot go crazy and C.C is hit by a sharp piece of rock and while out cold she utters her real name, Lelouch repeated it again. the scene i mention about her talking about snow is before the battle after Lelouch used his power to prevent the watch post from reporting back about the Black Knights in the area

Comment: Also i doesn't have to be the anime, any canon reference is good as i am quite sure C.C went under the name C.C in Jet Black Renya which would mean it's not an assigned name to Directors of the Geass Order

Comment: remember i am asking about what C.C and V.V means, if they represent their real names please make sure you include that

Comment: If you are talking about when V.V and Charles first met i'm pretty sure it's when Lelouch traps himself and Charles in the Sword of Akasha and Charles is explaining why he wants to destroy God (because God allows the difference in humans which sparks the conflicts which saw his family torn apart). i think it's the 4th last Episode (it's just before Lelouch is made emperor)

Comment: @Memor-X this is all I could find, check at the top.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of chapter 40 of the manga "Code Geass: Renya of Darkness", we now know that these names had no relation to the original names, but instead followed an alphabetical naming sequence. This is shown when C.C. says that the successor or "U.U." would be called V.V.
[image: Renya of Darkness ch.40 p.179]

Comment: interesting, it shows that V.V has 18 predecessors bellow C.C and the Nun C.C got her code from is probably called B.B. but then it begs the question, why such a naming scheme given that you'll run into problems after 26 (who comes after Z.Z). also i haven't read *Renya of Darkness* properly yet but if V.V is U.U's successor, why does it fall on Shiori to "create a new flow as V.V". if V.V is U.U's successor shouldn't that mean it's U.U doing that? also at some point succession has been broken as C.C is still there so then how would D.D become a successor?

Answer (score 1):

If you can read lips, at some point Lelouch correctly guesses the name of C.C:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spoilers Code Geass movies and series

> In the 2019 movie Code Geass Lelouch of the Re;surrection (Re;surrection), Lelouch takes on the name L.L. This suggests C.C. and V.V. are based on real names that begin with, resp, C and V.