# What is C2's actual name?

Tags: code-geass

What is the actual name of character c2 in the anime code geass? I would also like to know the name of v2 if that is possible.

Comment: @Mindwin Memor-X claimed in his first sentence that it isn't a duplicate. Though, as far as I remember, the name was never mentioned.

Comment: @PeterRaeves if Memor-X says so, so be it. About the name, it was mentioned by C.C. to Lelouch in the waterfall cave, but without voice acting (muffled by the waterfall sound). See the answer by Prix http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13158/2808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answered here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13158/2808).

It is unknown by design. C2's name is obscured when she tells it to Lelouch in the cave (first sesason, episode 5 to 8 -ish).

Nowhere it is written, and given the producers inclination to secrecy, it won't be revealed.

It is speculated that the name begins with the letter C, but that is all.